# Unit testing Jetpack Compose non UI functions?

Tags: android, kotlin, unit-testing, android-jetpack-compose

I'm writing a library for Jetpack Compose that exposes a lot of state functions that don't require UI. Is there a way to test composable functions without doing an instrumented test?

Comment: https://medium.com/@sebaslogen/blazing-fast-compose-tests-with-robolectric-b059f5471495

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [molecule](https://github.com/cashapp/molecule) to generate a Flow for a Composable function. Each time the function recomposes, its return value is emitted by the Flow.

You may also want to consider adding [mockposable](https://github.com/jeppeman/mockposable) to your testing toolkit.